# Heatmaps with frequency values as color var

Tags: r, heatmap

I need help with **heatmaps**, I am first timer and I usually have problems when coming to frequencies graphs.

I need to create a heatmap with `date` on `x` axis, and `crepus` on `y` axis. That is fine.

The variable I want for the **color** is the frequency of all species (`speciesname`), which would be the total sum of all species of the variable `nmb_individuals`, obviously by `date` and `crepus` value.

When trying it, I get a completely blank heatmap, though the scale looks good:

```
our_data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(date,crepus,fill=nmb_individuals)) + geom_tile()
```

Find a small portion of my dataset here:

```
      our_data <- structure(list(speciesname = c("Wood Lark", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "bunting sp.", 
"Robin", "Blackbird", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Chaffinch", "Chaffinch", 
"Chaffinch", "Chaffinch", "Cirl Bunting", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Redwing", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Chaffinch", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Blackbird", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Redwing", "Redwing", "Redwing", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Raven", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Skylark", "Blackbird", "Blackbird", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Chaffinch", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Blackbird", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Blackbird", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Redwing", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Redwing", "Redwing", "Chaffinch", "Song Thrush", 
"Dunnock", "Dunnock", "Dunnock", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Dunnock", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Chaffinch", "Blackbird", "Song Thrush", 
"Redwing", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Skylark", 
"Skylark", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Redwing", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Chaffinch", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Redwing", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Blackbird", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Redwing", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Blackbird", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Dunnock", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Redwing", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", "Song Thrush", 
"Song Thrush", "Redwing"), date = structure(c(18556, 18556, 18556, 
18556, 18557, 18557, 18557, 18557, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 
18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 
18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 
18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 
18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 
18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 
18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 
18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18560, 18560, 
18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 
18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 
18562, 18562, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 
18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 
18563, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 
18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18559, 18559, 
18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 
18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18560, 18560, 
18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18561, 18561, 18561, 
18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 
18561, 18561, 18561, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 
18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 
18562, 18562, 18563, 18563, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 
18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 
18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18556, 18558, 18558, 
18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18559, 18559, 18559, 
18559, 18559, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18564, 
18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18557, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 
18558, 18558, 18558, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18560, 
18560, 18560, 18560, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18562, 18562, 
18562, 18562, 18562, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 
18563, 18563, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18556, 18556, 18556, 18556, 
18557, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18559, 18559, 
18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 
18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18559, 18560, 18560, 18560, 
18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18560, 18561, 18561, 18561, 
18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 18561, 
18561, 18561, 18561, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 18562, 
18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 18563, 
18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564, 18564
), class = "Date"), nmb_individuals = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), crepus = c(0.974008207934337, 0.606019151846785, 
0.993160054719562, 0.997264021887825, 0.987738419618529, 0.990463215258856, 
0.991825613079019, 0.997275204359673, 0.99320652173913, 0.998641304347826, 
0.99320652173913, 0.99320652173913, 0.994565217391304, 0.995923913043478, 
0.997282608695652, 0.998641304347826, 0.989130434782609, 0.990489130434783, 
0.994565217391304, 0.995923913043478, 0.99320652173913, 0.144458281444583, 
0.175591531755915, 0.196762141967621, 0.198007471980075, 0.206724782067248, 
0.209215442092154, 0.231631382316314, 0.239103362391034, 0.2640099626401, 
0.273972602739726, 0.278953922789539, 0.288916562889166, 0.311332503113325, 
0.328767123287671, 0.342465753424658, 0.36239103362391, 0.371108343711083, 
0.378580323785803, 0.379825653798257, 0.386052303860523, 0.387297633872976, 
0.398505603985056, 0.396014943960149, 0.407222914072229, 0.409713574097136, 
0.413449564134496, 0.414694894146949, 0.205479452054795, 0.422166874221669, 
0.419676214196762, 0.424657534246575, 0.427148194271482, 0.432129514321295, 
0.433374844333749, 0.434620174346202, 0.442092154420922, 0.443337484433375, 
0.452054794520548, 0.455790784557908, 0.463262764632628, 0.468244084682441, 
0.470734744707347, 0.474470734744707, 0.481942714819427, 0.485678704856787, 
0.489414694894147, 0.493150684931507, 0.420921544209215, 0.499377334993773, 
0.520547945205479, 0.980074719800747, 0.457036114570361, 0.0844504021447721, 
0.100536193029491, 0, 0.00536193029490617, 0.193029490616622, 
0.24798927613941, 0.319034852546917, 0.420911528150134, 0.953083109919571, 
0.978552278820375, 0.978552278820375, 0.981233243967828, 0.986595174262735, 
0.987935656836461, 0.997319034852547, 0.127005347593583, 0.0922459893048128, 
0.729946524064171, 0.556149732620321, 0.967914438502674, 0.983957219251337, 
0.99331550802139, 0.98936170212766, 0.279255319148936, 0.333776595744681, 
0.337765957446809, 0.396276595744681, 0.454787234042553, 0.51063829787234, 
0.57313829787234, 0.651595744680851, 0.69813829787234, 0.933510638297872, 
0.977393617021277, 0.982712765957447, 0.986702127659575, 0.00265957446808511, 
0.320478723404255, 0.337765957446809, 0.202917771883289, 0.364721485411141, 
0.36604774535809, 0.482758620689655, 0.485411140583555, 0.493368700265252, 
0.502652519893899, 0.510610079575597, 0.523872679045093, 0.555702917771883, 
0.653846153846154, 0.693633952254642, 0.805039787798409, 0.992042440318302, 
0.00397877984084881, 0.771929824561403, 0.883940620782726, 0.885290148448043, 
0.892037786774629, 0.902834008097166, 0.906882591093117, 0.815718157181572, 
0.990514905149051, 0.991869918699187, 0.989159891598916, 0.0542005420054201, 
0.838753387533875, 0.888888888888889, 0.894308943089431, 0.897018970189702, 
0.905149051490515, 0.993224932249322, 0.990514905149051, 0.348586810228802, 
0.363391655450875, 0.10228802153432, 0.422611036339166, 0.374158815612382, 
0.386271870794078, 0.390309555854643, 0.426648721399731, 0.994638069705094, 
0.894101876675603, 0.978552278820375, 0.207774798927614, 0.946380697050938, 
0, 0.0134048257372654, 0.0790884718498659, 0.301608579088472, 
0.592493297587131, 0.983914209115281, 0.985254691689008, 0.987935656836461, 
0.989276139410188, 0.994638069705094, 0.990641711229946, 0.358288770053476, 
0.364973262032086, 0.43716577540107, 0.46524064171123, 0.479946524064171, 
0.487967914438503, 0.540106951871658, 0.574866310160428, 0.596256684491979, 
0.606951871657754, 0.64572192513369, 0.885026737967914, 0.927807486631016, 
0.957219251336898, 0.962566844919786, 0.977272727272727, 0.0944148936170213, 
0.622340425531915, 0.0013262599469496, 0.00663129973474801, 0.431034482758621, 
0.513262599469496, 0.53183023872679, 0.586206896551724, 0.588859416445623, 
0.590185676392573, 0.610079575596817, 0.690981432360743, 0.714854111405836, 
0.814323607427056, 0.872679045092838, 0.973474801061008, 0.990716180371353, 
0.993368700265252, 0.996021220159151, 0.625994694960212, 0.880636604774536, 
0.993368700265252, 0.998635743519782, 0.901084010840108, 0.915989159891599, 
0.91869918699187, 0.575880758807588, 0.739837398373984, 0.761517615176152, 
0.897018970189702, 0.913279132791328, 0.906882591093117, 0.804318488529015, 
0.850202429149798, 0.910931174089069, 0.919028340080972, 0.989304812834225, 
0.994652406417112, 0.994652406417112, 0.216755319148936, 0.264627659574468, 
0.832446808510638, 0.590185676392573, 0.704244031830239, 0.720159151193634, 
0.976127320954907, 0.981432360742706, 0.995918367346939, 0.159891598915989, 
0.474254742547425, 0.982384823848238, 0.986449864498645, 0.997289972899729, 
0.998644986449864, 0.998644986449864, 0.908232118758435, 0.909581646423752, 
0.913630229419703, 0.916329284750337, 0.910931174089069, 0.109017496635262, 
0.131897711978466, 0.995962314939435, 0.34185733512786, 0.998659517426273, 
0.39142091152815, 0.977211796246649, 0.991957104557641, 0.983957219251337, 
0.982620320855615, 0.987967914438503, 0.990641711229946, 0.970588235294118, 
0.190159574468085, 0.202127659574468, 0.280585106382979, 0.359042553191489, 
0.410904255319149, 0.69281914893617, 0.784574468085106, 0.992021276595745, 
0.981432360742706, 0.986737400530504, 0.986737400530504, 0.980900409276944, 
0.982264665757162, 0.987721691678035, 0.993178717598909, 0.99047619047619, 
0.975609756097561, 0.98780487804878, 0.00948509485094851, 0.848238482384824, 
0.952574525745257, 0.967479674796748, 0.913630229419703, 0.916329284750337, 
0.52361673414305, 0.596491228070176, 0.631578947368421, 0.62753036437247, 
0.658569500674764, 0.890688259109312, 0.878542510121457, 0.87719298245614, 
0.870445344129555, 0.851551956815115, 0.816464237516869, 0.977058029689609, 
0.98110661268556, 0.902834008097166, 0.913630229419703, 0.0969044414535666, 
0.395693135935397, 0.707940780619112, 0.95693135935397, 0.969044414535666, 
0.983849259757739, 0.986541049798116, 0.991924629878869, 0.995962314939435, 
0.0804289544235925, 0.414209115281501, 0.481233243967828, 0.509383378016086, 
0.560321715817694, 0.60053619302949, 0.719839142091153, 0.966487935656837, 
0.975871313672922, 0.978552278820375, 0.981233243967828, 0.986595174262735, 
0.989276139410188, 0.990616621983914, 0.99597855227882, 0.0053475935828877, 
0.977272727272727, 0.982620320855615, 0.983957219251337, 0.99331550802139, 
0.997326203208556, 0.155585106382979, 0.38563829787234, 0.646276595744681, 
0.924202127659575, 0.941489361702128, 0.974734042553192, 0.981382978723404, 
0.997340425531915, 0.518617021276596, 0.570291777188329, 0.749336870026525, 
0.904509283819629, 0.956233421750663, 0.960212201591512, 0.96551724137931, 
0.970822281167109, 0.985411140583554, 0.53448275862069)), row.names = c(NA, 
-345L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this kind:

```
our_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date,crepus)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill= factor(nmb_individuals)), height = 0.1)
```

or without factor:

```
our_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date,crepus)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill= nmb_individuals), height = 0.1)
```